# C++ - Object-Oriented Array of base class

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning C++: polymorphism and slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing)
>   [Array of polymorphic base class objects initialized with child class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203590/array-of-polymorphic-base-class-objects-initialized-with-child-class-objects)

I've integrated object oriented classes into my OpenGL application. The base class has a function called `Tick` that should get called every tick (obvious) with a parameter representing the delta time. Here's how it looks like (without the irrelevant things for this question).

Headers:

```
class Object
{
public:
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime);
}
class Controller : public Object
{
public:
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime);
}
```

Then I have a class called `Engine` that contains the main loop, initializations and disposal (to separate it from the window creation).
In that class I need to keep track of all the objects in the game, so I created an array:
`Object* Objects = new Object[10]; // for now max 10 objects`

Then to call the tick function I iterated trough the array:

```
for (unsigned int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
    Objects[c].Tick(delta);
```

Being `delta` calculated before the loop.

The problem is that if I assign one of the objects in the array to a `Controller` (for example) the Tick function called is always the one that's in `Object` and not in the class that's actually stored.

I even tried type casting (each class has a string to identify it's type), with no avail.

I'm pretty sure that the answer is something obvious (like the answer to my last questions), but I can't find the answer.

Thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have encountered the [slicing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

The solution is to not store polymorphic objects by value in an array; use (smart) pointers instead.

Comment: Thank you, would have been easy to find an answer if I knew the keyword slicing.

So the problem is fixed by using an array of pointers of type `Object`, thank you :)

(once again, simple answer lol)